# variational inequality

Tags: stochastic-analysis, optimal-control

Consider the following dynamics

\begin{align}
dX_{s} &= a(s,X_{s},Y_{s},Z_{s})ds + \sigma(s,X_{s},Y_{s},Z_{s})dW_s \\
X_{t}&=x \, (\in\mathbb{R}^{n})
\end{align}
and the associated payoff functional
\begin{align}
J(t,x,Y,Z) = \mathbb{E}[\int_{t}^{T}f(s,X_{s},Y_{s},Z_{s})ds + g(X_{T})]
\end{align}
My question, is how to write the variational inequality concerning the problem
\begin{align}
V(t,x) = \inf_{z}\sup_{y}J(t,x,y,z)
\end{align}

Comment: yes, W is a d-dimensional BM